Update QLIK Data Connection of type Amazon S3 with new IAM Access key and Secret Key using QLIK Rest API
I have a requirement to update QLIK Data connection of type Amazon S3 using QLIK API through an automated script.
We rotate our IAM access keys every 90 days. So, we have to update our QLIK Amazon S3 Data connection automatically using API calls for every 90 days.
I have followed QLIK API documentation and able to list connections in QLIK using API key. I have got all the parameters from the output of this.
{
      "created": "2024-06-12T12:58:41.613Z",
      "datasourceID": "File_AmazonS3Connector",
      "id": "id",
      "links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "qlik-uri"
        }
      },
      "privileges": [
        "change_owner",
        "change_space",
        "delete",
        "list",
        "read",
        "update"
      ],
      "qArchitecture": 0,
      "qConnectStatement": "connect-statement",
      "qCredentialsID": "id",
      "qEngineObjectID": "OID",
      "qID": "Qid",
      "qLogOn": 1,
      "qName": "Amazon_S3",
      "qSeparateCredentials": false,
      "qType": ".exe",
      "qri": "s3-uri",
      "tags": null,
      "tenant": "tenant",
      "updated": "2024-06-12T12:58:41.613Z",
      "user": "user",
      "version": "V1"
    }

Tried multiple ways to make API call using CURL requests to update Data connection of type Amazon S3.
But not able to edit the Data connection passing access key and secret key to it. Tried to pass them to qConnectionSecret parameter in API call. But it isn't working.
I am getting Bad request error with error code:400
Please help me with curl command/ python request for the above requirement. Thanks in advance!!

Currently editing isn't supported on Qlik Cloud. The recommendation is to delete the data connection and recreate it (reference) in the same space with the same name. Since data loads reference the space and name (e.g. LIB CONNECT TO 'MySpace:Amazon_S3'; ), your reloads will not be affected.

Could you provide any documentation for it? I don't find it anywhere where Qlik does not support edits using API.
